# How to find generic entity types and apply in entity framework modelbuilder?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an interface that represents views of database.

```
public interface IView { }
```

And I want to use modelbilder to set `HasNoKey()` method.

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
 {       
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IView>(buildAction =>
        {
            buildAction.HasNoKey();
        });


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
 }
```

But this throws an exception. Can I implement this using reflection or is there any solution in entity framework core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate all the model types in OnModelCreating.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var t in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where( t => typeof(IView).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType)))
        {
            t.IsKeyless = true;
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: But I did not add a property in `DbContext` as `DbSet<MyClass>`. I am setting it dynamically in service class like folowing `context.Set<MyClass>()`. So your solution throws exception Cannot create a DbSet for 'MyClass' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Comment: Then you have to add the Entity Type, but that's a different question.

Comment: Can I set entity type in this foreach loop?

Comment: No that's looping over the Entity types that EF has configured based on the DbSet<T> properties.  If you want to add Entity Types you would call `modelBuilder.Model.AddEntityType(typeof(MyEntityType));` first.